# Trouble converting string to int and using it on a for loop

Tags: sh, zsh

I'm a shell script beginner here, and I'm having some trouble with something *- oddly specific -* that I haven't found help for.

For sheer fun, I tried to code something that you feed a string into and that runs that through `yes` and `lolcat`, for cool rainbow text.

Something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHNpn.png).

The code is pretty straightforward, and uses `$((...))` to convert a string (the number of times the user wants its string to be repeated) to an integer.

Anyways, here's the code. I've tried moving the point in the script where the string is converted, but nothing.

```sh
echo Lolcat_repeater: A wonderful tool that does absolutely nothing.
echo [I] Input a string to lol:
echo [P] :: && read input
echo [I] Times to repeat [ENTER for endless]:
echo [P] :: && read repeats
$repeats=$(($repeats))
if [ $repeats == "" ]
then
    yes $input | lolcat
else
    for ((i=1; i<=$repeats; i++))
    do
        echo $input | lolcat
    done
fi
```

This error always pops up:

```
./lolcat_repeater.sh: 11: Syntax error: Bad for loop variable
```

And, judging by how the code doesn't execute `yes $input | lolcat` when I just hit ENTER, I clearly messed something up in the conditional.

I know I probably sound stupid right now, but any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I guess that `repeats` contains a bogus value. Please also put a `echo $ZSH_VERSION` in your script and report what version is printed. BTW, why is this also tagged by _sh_? Your program isn't valid sh code anyway.

Comment: There aren't separate string and int types in `zsh`. Assignments to variables don't use `$`, so the correct syntax would be `repeats=$((repeats))`, but that doesn't do anything useful.

Comment: `zsh`, by the way, has a specific `repeat` loop: `repeat $repeats do echo $input | lolcat; done`.